# Access SparkUI of a running Spark job on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am running Spark on Kubernetes and need to monitor the Spark Job in runtime.
How can I access the SparkUI page of my job while it's running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Enable port forwarding for the Spark driver pod:

```sh
kubectl port-forward <driver-pod-name> 4040:4040
```

2. Access the SparkUI from your web via `http://localhost:4040`

---

You can also make sure SparkUI is running by looking for the relevant log:

```sh
kubectl logs <driver-pod-name> | grep SparkUI
```

Example output:

> 21/11/22 09:50:21 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI'
> on port 4040. 21/11/22 09:50:21 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to
> 0.0.0.0, and started at http://spark-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-driver-svc.spark.svc:4040